# component gives data to another component through one controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I want component dbServerTable to give data to dbServerInfoSidebar when a list item from dbServerTable's template is clicked, but no data is being displayed in dbServerInfoSidebar.

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('SplashDamageApp').component('dbServerTable', {
        templateUrl: 'dbServerTable.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
    });
})(window.angular);



(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('SplashDamageApp').component('dbServerInfoSidebar', {
        templateUrl: 'dbServerInfoSidebar.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
    });
})(window.angular);
```

They both share the same controller.

```
//AppCtrl
    $scope.selectServer = function(item)
    {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;
    }


// dbServerTable.html
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | orderBy:'name'"  data-ng-click="selectServer(item)">
        <td>{{item.display_name}}</td>
</tr>

//dbServerInfoSidebar.html
<h1>{{selectedItem}}</h1>
```

When I click a list item, selectServer() grabs the item, which it does, and it should pass it to the dbServerInfoSidebar.html, but it doesn't.

Can someone show me how to make this data connect? Code examples are welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create two components, but you expect them to share the same instance of the `AppCtrl` controller. This is not the case. Two instances of the `AppCtrl` will be created. One for each component. Manipulating `$scope.selectedItem` in the `dbServerTable` component will not change the value of `$scope.selectedItem` in the `dbServerInfoSidebar`.

What you want to achieve, can be done by creating a service which will be injected in the controllers. On this service, you can set the `selectedItem`. Services are created as a singleton by default. This means both controllers will get the same instance of the service. This way, when you change the value of `selectedItem` in the service, the changes will be reflected in both components.

An example:

```
// The shared service
(function(angular) {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('SplashDamageApp').service('DbServerService', function() {
            this.selectedItem  = undefined;

        });
})(window.angular);

// AppCtrl
(function(angular) {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('SplashDamageApp').controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'DbServerService', function($scope, DbServerService) {
            $scope.getSelectedItem = function() {
                return DbServerService.selectedItem;
            }

            $scope.setSelectedItem = function(item) {
                DbServerService.selectedItem = item;
            }

        });
}])(window.angular);


// dbServerTable.html
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | orderBy:'name'"  data-ng-click="setSelectedItem(item)">
    <td>{{item.display_name}}</td>
</tr>

//dbServerInfoSidebar.html
<h1>{{getSelectedItem()}}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way you could make a quick code mock up of what you are describing?

Comment: I added a brief example, I hope it will help.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you!